# How do I link to a local file in Trello?

Tags: trello, markdown

I'd like to create links to files stored locally in Trello, e.g. `C:\my_docs\myfile.c`

I've read that you can use Markdown language in the description field of a card, but in testing this, I've had no luck getting a local link (non `http:\\...`) to work.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Windows

Here are some examples which may be accepted by some applications on Windows systems, referring to the same, local file c:\WINDOWS\clock.avi

file://localhost/c|/WINDOWS/clock.avi
file:///c|/WINDOWS/clock.avi
file://localhost/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi

Here is the correct URI as understood by the Windows Shell API:

file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi

For a local file, the last is the most obvious and human-readable, and also the canonical one understood by the operating system